# View Changes While scrolling RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using `RecyclerView`, I have one `ImageButton` as Child view, I'm changing the background of that `ImageButton` on click.

Now my problem is when change Image of `ImageButton` by clicking and than scroll up again scroll to the top, the state of set to the initial stage. I tried everything but its not happening. help me with that.

**My Adapter class**

```
public class ViewAllAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductHolder> {

    int[] objects;
    Context context;
    Boolean flag = false;

    public ViewAllAdapter(int[] objects, Context context) {
        super();
        this.objects = objects;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return objects.length;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductHolder arg0, int arg1) {
        arg0.title.setText("Product" + arg1 + 1);
        arg0.aPrice.setPaintFlags(arg0.aPrice.getPaintFlags()
                | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        arg0.aPrice.setText("\u20B9" + " " + "5000");
        arg0.off.setText("56% off");
        arg0.price.setText("\u20B9" + " " + "2300");
        arg0.mainImage.setImageResource(objects[arg1]);
        arg0.ratings.setRating(4f);
        arg0.clickme.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        ProductDetailsPage.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        arg0.wish.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart);
        arg0.wish.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!flag) {
                    arg0.wish.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heartfade);
                    YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(550)
                            .playOn(arg0.wish);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Product Added to wish list..",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    flag = true;
                } else {
                    arg0.wish.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart);
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Product Removed to wish list..",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public ProductHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(arg0.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewall_item, arg0, false);
        return new ProductHolder(view);
    }

    public class ProductHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView title;
        protected TextView aPrice;
        protected TextView off;
        protected TextView price;
        protected ImageView mainImage;
        protected RatingBar ratings;
        protected ImageButton wish;
        protected RelativeLayout clickme;

        public ProductHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
            aPrice = (TextView) itemView
                    .findViewById(R.id.productActualPrice);
            off = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.offPrice);
            price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productPrice);
            mainImage = (ImageView) itemView
                    .findViewById(R.id.productImage);
            wish = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToWishList);
            ratings = (RatingBar) itemView
                    .findViewById(R.id.productRatings);
            clickme = (RelativeLayout) itemView
                    .findViewById(R.id.clickToGO);

        }
    }
}
```

And in My **MainActicity** I'm doing

```
rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.gvViewAll);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),
            2);
    rv.setLayoutManager(glm);

    final ViewAllAdapter adp = new ViewAllAdapter(productImage,
            getApplicationContext());
    rv.setAdapter(adp);

    rvh = (RecyclerViewHeader) findViewById(R.id.header);
    rvh.attachTo(rv, true);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: maintain a state variable in your model and set setImageResource according to state

Comment: I tried to make my `ImageButton` static but it says "static types can only be declared in static or top level types".

Comment: change your data model you took int[] object array . change it somthing like Model[] object;  and Model{ int imageId ,boolean state }

Comment: you need to hold the state of item which you have clicked

Answer (score 0):

As per your Custom RecyclerView adapter, I suggest you to use HashMap to store Values. After all Data Model is best option to load data in to RecyclerView.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMapTest = new HashMap<>();
```

When user click on ImageButton then add following code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(hashMapTest.get(position) != null && hashMapTest.get(position) != false) {
                    // Code of Product Added to wish list..
                    hashMapTest.put(getPosition(), 1);
                } else {
                    // Code of Product Removed to wish list..
                    hashMapTest.put(getPosition(), 0);
                }

            }
        });
```

In your onBindViewHolder(ProductHolder holder, int position) add following code

```
if(hashMapTest.get(position) != null && hashMapTest.get(position) != false) {
            // Show your ImageButton color Product Added to wish list..
        } else {
            // Show your ImageButton color Product Removed to wish list..
        }
```

Hope it helps you.